# How to sort a list after AddRange?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

new to C#, SQL and Linq. I have two lists, one "dataTransactions" (fuel from gas stations) and a similar one "dataTransfers" (fuel from slip tanks).

They each access a different table from SQL and get combined later.

```
        List<FuelLightTruckDataSource> data = new List<FuelLightTruckDataSource>();

        using (SystemContext ctx = new SystemContext())
        {

            List<FuelLightTruckDataSource> dataTransactions
                = ctx.FuelTransaction
                    .Where(tx => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(tx.DateTime) >= from.Date && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(tx.DateTime) <= to.Date
                        //&& tx.AssetFilled.AssignedToEmployee.Manager
                        && tx.AssetFilled.AssignedToEmployee != null
                        //&
                        && tx.AssetFilled.AssetType.Code == "L"
                        && (tx.FuelProductType.FuelProductClass.Code == "GAS" || tx.FuelProductType.FuelProductClass.Code == "DSL"))
                    .GroupBy(tx => new { tx.AssetFilled, tx.DateTime, tx.FuelProductType.FuelProductClass, tx.FuelCard.FuelVendor, tx.City, tx.Volume, tx.Odometer}) //Added tx.volume to have individual transactions
                    .Select(g => new FuelLightTruckDataSource()
                    {
                        Asset = g.FirstOrDefault().AssetFilled,
                        Employee = g.FirstOrDefault().AssetFilled.AssignedToEmployee,
                        ProductClass = g.FirstOrDefault().FuelProductType.FuelProductClass,
                        Vendor = g.FirstOrDefault().FuelCard.FuelVendor,
                        FillSource = FuelFillSource.Transaction,
                        Source = "Fuel Station",
                        City = g.FirstOrDefault().City.ToUpper(),
                        Volume = g.FirstOrDefault().Volume,
                        Distance = g.FirstOrDefault().Odometer,
                        Date = g.FirstOrDefault().DateTime

                    })
                    .ToList();
```

In the end, I use

```
            data.AddRange(dataTransactions);
            data.AddRange(dataTransfers);
```

to put the two lists together and generate a fuel consumption report. 
Both lists are individually sorted by Date, but after "AddRange" the "dataTransfers" just gets added to the end, losing my sort by Date. How do I sort the combined result again by date after using the "AddRange" command?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
data = data.OrderBy(d => d.Date).ToList();
```

Or if you want to order descending:

```
data = data.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).ToList();
```

Comment: Excellent. It worked well.
One other issue, I need to calculate distance traveled based on odometer reading. How do I access the current and previous values of that "data" list to calculate that distance?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `List<T>.Sort(delegate)`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx

Example:

```
data.Sort(delegate(FuelLightTruckDataSource x, FuelLightTruckDataSource y)
{
    // your sort logic here.
});
```

Advantage: this sort doesn't create a new `IList<T>` instance as it does in `OrderBy`. it's a small thing, but to some people this matters, especially for performance and memory sensitive situations.